# Calculate area of a parallelogram given its sides and the angle between diagonals

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, area

The parallelogram `ABCD` has sides `AB = 80 cm` and `BC = 60 cm`. Let `X` be the intersection of its diagonals. How to calculate the area of the parallelogram, when given the angle between diagonals `BXC = 60°`.

I have calculated the angle `AXB = 120°` and written two equations based on the cosine law, but it has started to be complicated and I hope there is more elegant way.

[Picture of the Parallelogram with the given values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWa3i.png)

Comment: With cosine law you are on the right track: Give a name a=XB=XD, b=XA=XC; find two equations with the 2 unknowns $a$ and $b$ then solve the resulting system.

Comment: Thanks, actually that's what I did and got this result: [link to WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos60+%3D+(a*a%2Bb*b-60*60)%2F(2ab),+cos120+%3D+(a*a%2Bb*b-80*80)%2F(2ab)). It results in system of 2 quadratic equations which is quite complex and time consuming to solve. Is that the only possible way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the law of cosines. You write the following system:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
   80^2=x^2+y^2-2xy\cos120°\\60^2=x^2+y^2-2xy\cos60°
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $x$=$AX$ and $y$=$BX$.

Subtracting the equations:
\begin{equation}
   80^2-60^2=x^2+y^2-2xy\cos120°-(x^2+y^2-2xy\cos60°)
\end{equation}
we have:

$2800=-2xy(\cos120°-\cos60°)$

$2800=-2xy(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2})$

$2800=2xy$

so $xy=1400$

Now you can just calculate the area of the two triangles ABX and BCX using:

\begin{equation}
Area=\frac{1}{2}xy\sin\alpha, 
\end{equation}

where $\alpha$ is the angle between $x$ and $y$ (120° in ABX and 60° in BCX). Then it is easy.

Comment: Thanks for great answer :)

Comment: Good short circuit compared to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let us work in meters in order to work with small numbers.

Setting $a=XB=XD, b=XA=XC,$  the law of cosines gives:

- In triangle ABX :

$$\tag{1}a^2+b^2+ab=0.8^2  \ \ \text{because} \ \ \cos(2\pi/3)=-1/2.$$

- In triangle BCX :

$$\tag{2}a^2+b^2-ab=0.6^2   \ \ \text{because} \ \ \cos(\pi/3)=1/2.$$

The by adding and subtracting (1) and (2), we obtain the following system:

$$\cases{a^2+b^2=0.5\\ab=0.14}.$$

By squaring both sides of the second equation, setting $A=a^2,B=b^2$, we obtain:

$$\cases{A+B=0.5\\AB=0.0196}.$$

Thus $A$ and $B$ are solutions of quadratic equation $X^2- 0.5 X + 0.0196=0$ that will not be difficult to solve: $A=0.0428768$ and $B=0.457123$. From which 
$a=\sqrt{A}=0.207067$ and $b=\sqrt{B}=0.676109$. It it the values (divided by 100) found through Wolfram, throwing away negatives ones.)

Then you proceed by computing areas of triangles XBC and XCD using formula: length of a side $\times$ length of another side $\times \sin$(angle) (angle between these sides).

Comment: Thanks for answer, one thing not clear to me is the `a^2 + b^2 = 1` part, shouldn't it be more like this: `a^2 + b^2 = 0.5`?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I have forgotten to divide by 2... I correct it.

Comment: Ok, thanks once more, now its clear :)